# Restoring selected iOS apps and data to my new iPhone

Tags: iphone

I made a full backup of my old iPhone 4S (iOS 7.1) with iTunes. I'd like to restore only some of the apps and app data to my new 5s from the iTunes backup. Is this possible?

I don't need much of the apps figuring in the iTunes backup just a few games along with their scores which were saved off my old iphone. Thx in advance.

Comment: Any reason you don't want to just restore from the backup then delete the apps etc. you don't want from on your phone manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: apart from iCloud selective app backup which implies that you need to fully restore the new iphone, you can use [this to back up and restore only selected apps](http://www.copytrans.net/copytransapps.php) and app preferences that go along.

Otherwise create another backup of your old iphone, this time via using iCloud. (Settings > iCloud > Storage & Backup > Manage Storage). From the options on the next screen, choose which and app data you want to back up exactly. Then hit "Back Up Now".

[image]

Upon restore to your new iphone only the app data you selected during the icloud backup will be restored.

Comment: The page shown above is for the Documents & Data iCloud service, not iCloud backup, therefore restoring from iCloud backup won't care what you select in the above preferences. Also I'd appreciate attribution when copying my screenshots.

Comment: Hi George, thanks for the note and sorry for using your screenshot without attribution. I have since made the correct screenshot on my iPhone and added it to my answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Even though this is an older post with a marked answer, I still want to address the question since this page ranks highly in search engines and it's a problem I've been actively working on.

Here's a link to a blog post I wrote about a tool I made for "filtering" a backup made in iTunes so it only contains the data you want to keep: https://deciphertools.com/blog/selective-iphone-backup/ We started the tool because people wanted to transfer Apple Watch Activity data without restoring an entire backup, and it's grown up from there.

You can filter by app, keeping data for only some apps, as the original poster wanted :)